# Как убрать дубли слов [:de]500 ml[:en]500 ml[:] в строке?

Tags: php

вот есть такая строка [:en]Blooming Sky[:], [:de]500 ml[:en]500 ml[:]
а надо или так  Blooming Sky 500 ml
или такая
[:en]Black Brown[:de]Black Brown[:]500 ml[:]
а надо Black Brown 500 ml

или такаая
Pastels -[:de]Blue Mist[:en]Blue Mist[:] [:de]500 ml[:en]500 ml[:];
а надо Pastels - Blue Mist 500 ml

Comment: Пройтись циклом по строке, найти дубли и убрать их.

Comment: Так и не ясно какие дубли. В приведённых примерах нет дублей

Comment: вот дубли 500 ml в этой строке
 [:en]Blooming Sky[:], [:de]500 ml[:en]500 ml[:]
и вот дубли тут Black Brown  [:en]Black Brown[:de]Black Brown[:]500 ml[:]
а ,как циклом сделать если у каждого товара свое название и объем ?

Answer (score 0):

```php
$input = '-[:de]Blue Mist[:en]Blue Mist[:] [:de]500 ml[:en]500 ml[:]';
// 1. режем строку по конструкции типа [:de]
$input = preg_split('/\[\:.*?\]/i',$input);
// 2. чистка, и проверка
$input = array_map('trim',$input);
$input = array_filter($input);
$input = array_unique($input);

$output = implode(' ',$input);
```

Comment: а можно так-то вырезать объем   500 ml или возможно 700 ml и 1000ml чтобы обернуть его в спан ?
то есть как  разделить на 2 строки 1)[:de]Blue Mist[:en]Blue Mist[:] 2) [:de]500 ml[:en]500 ml[:] и вторую после обработки скриптом выше добавить в переменную и перенести в спан или может есть лучше решение?

Comment: можно)) смотрите, ищите, весь код писать за вас не буду)

Comment: а регулярку не подскажите разделения на 2 строки ?
чтобы верезало  от [: тут буквы ] до [:] включая скобки
или правильней по разделителю [:]

Comment: она уже у меня в ответе